# bx lr not working in ARM assembly on Raspberry Pi

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm writing a program using ARM assembly to serve as an interface for a gas pump. The user selects the grade of gasoline they would like to pump, and then declares the amount of money they would like to spend. Since the same checks are performed for this input regardless of the grade of gasoline, I would like to use the same block of code. I want my code to use `bl` and `bx lr` as seen [here](http://computerscience.chemeketa.edu/armTutorial/Functions/BranchLink.html), but I'm doing something wrong. Here's a sample of my code:

```
get_grade:
    cmpne r1, #'R'
    beq pump_regular
    cmpne r1, #'P'
    beq pump_premium

pump_regular:
    ldr r0, =strSelRegular
    bl printf
    bl prompt_amount
    @ do other things

pump_premium:
    ldr r0, =strSelPremium
    bl printf
    bl prompt_amount
    @ do other things

prompt_amount:
    ldr r0, =numInputPattern
    ldr r1, =intBuyAmt
    bl scanf
    @ check to make sure the input is valid
    @ if not, b prompt_amount
    bx lr
```

This program compiles, but doesn't behave the way I'd expect. Once it reaches the end of `prompt_amount`, it hangs. I've been searching through forum posts and keil docs for a couple hours now to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand your code.  Where is the entry point?  Why is there no instruction returning from `get_grade`?  Another issue you need to watch out for is that each `bl` instruction overwrites the `lr` register.  So to be able to return from your function, you need to save `lr` on the stack on entry and pop it back off at the end.  You can use `push {lr}` and `pop {pc}` to do this, combining the `pop` instruction with the function return.

Comment: @fuz: To maintain stack alignment, you normally want to do something like `push {r4, lr}` / `pop {r4, pc}` even if you don't actually need to save/restore an extra call-preserved register.  (IIRC, the ABI on ARM Linux maintains 8-byte stack alignment before a call)

Comment: You are overwriting `lr` with `bl`. And since you return from the function by `bx lr` it keeps branching to `bx lr`, alas it hangs.

Answer (score 3):

Operation for BL instruction

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
  LR = address of the instruction after the branch instruction
  PC = PC + (SignExtend(signed_immed_24) << 2)
```

So one function calls another

```
bl one
one_ret:
```

The pc points at one and lr is changed to point at one_ret:

```
one:
```

At this point lr points at one_ret so a simple bx lr will return

```
...
bl two
two_ret:
```

After executing this bl lr points at two_ret, a bx lr will return to two_ret.  The
knowledge to return to one_ret is lost from an lr perspective

```
two:
bx lr
```

This branches to two_ret

```
two_ret:
bx lr
```

At this point this is an infinite loop bx lr branches to two_ret...no way to get back to one_ret

if you

```
...
bl one
one_ret:
...
one:
 push {r4,lr}
 bl two:
two_ret:
 pop {r4,lr}
 bx lr
two:
 bx lr
```

the push and pop preserve lr

```
one:
 push {r4,lr}  save lr pointing at one_ret on the stack
 ...
 pop {r4,lr} restore lr to point at one_ret
 bx lr branch to one_ret
```

r4 is not relevant here, it is common to see this register used.  The current calling convention wants a 64 bit aligned stack so need to push an even number of registers.  Sometimes you will see r3 for example instead of r4 but r3 could be part of a return (...maybe?) get much higher than r4 and you get into some special/reserved registers...just use r4, no magic to it, but for the current and prior calling conventions, r4 is a good choice...If you are actually saving other registers then use those, with eventually a total of an even number of registers (does not appear to have to be in one push/pop, but before you call another function)

Before thumb mov pc,lr was the typical return branch.  Then with thumb the desired instruction was bx lr because bx can handle mixed mode (arm/thumb) and mov pc,lr does/did not.  You can look for interworking in the documentation.  Then in addition pop {pc} will now work for interworking but it depends on the architecture armv4t does not support pop {pc} for interworking, it has to be from/to the same mode.  The raspberry pi aarch32 instruction sets (armv6 or armv7-a depending on the core you are using) both support the pop {pc} so you could change it to be

```
one:
push {r4,lr}
...
pop {r4,pc}
```

and save one instruction.

As a general rule whenever you bl to a label just like in a C function you should automatically type the { and } add the push {r4,lr} and pop {r4,pc} and then fill in the code in the middle.  Then you can optimize as in the case of two: above there is no use of bl in that "function" so lr does not need to be preserved, and if you have no other reason to use the stack then you can remove the push/pop and add the bx lr.

Note that bl does not support mixed mode BUT some toolchains might.  Between the assembler and the linker in gnu binutils for example if you mark the labels correctly:

```
.type two,%function
.globl two
two:
```

then the linker can see the bl two and know what mode that instruction is in and what mode the two code is and as needed add a trampoline

```
bl two
...
two:
```

if bl two is in thumb and two is in arm then the linker will essentially replace the bl two to branch to a trampoline

```
bl two_from_thumb
...
two:
...
two_from_thumb:
bx two
...
```

bx two is not valid they do some simple instructions to functionally do the same using a reserved register.  If your toolchain does not add a trampoline for you then you cannot just blindly bl to whatever you want...sometimes you have to do some form of add lr,pc,#something, adr rx,label, and bx rx, in pseudocode.  simulate a bl by pointing lr after the function call, and then using bx to branch
to the function.